# Can I increase a capacitor's working voltage by putting two capacitors in series and doubling the uF value? I am dealing with a 0.1uf rated @1700VDC

Tags: voltage, capacitor

The existing capacitors are being used in a Sencore PS148 scope. I am not able to find a 0.2 uF capacitor rated @ 1700VDC.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain to what you're trying to accomplish here "increase ... working voltage" vs "and doubling uF" If you want both, you should go for 4 caps in total, 2 pair in parallell, and those paris put in series.

Comment: It will help people answer if you clearly specify the required uF and voltage. At present this is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

To a first order yes, but depending on style of capacitors you might need resistors to balance the voltages.

Most film caps fine, but uneven leakage on electrolytic capacitors make stacking without balancing resistors unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure from your question if you need a 0.1µF capacitor rated for 1700VDC, or a 0.2uF rated for 1700VDC.

If it is 0.1uF, I found 3 on [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ceramic-capacitors/60?s=N4IgjCBcpgLFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXDAAYBWAZipALgrnkaoDYAOMTh8d2DW58eAJgoB2eo05VOnAJwiFo%2BUsYKqE0RL6iwNOBAKia7dqr2xBsCnqpbOuk1QXz2e7QuqeqFAZ4SNBKsIKrsYOx2JgoKYDx8XKLsNHwSEmB%2BfJx0mtmxNKkECtaCfLGKHozUXNHkFLB5jHA0sM7gthScdXCcNiIc6byMAnRF4JziFOoT2hJ1%2BjSS46bsWroAugQADgAuUCAAyrsATgCWAHYA5iAAvhqKCCDIkOjY%2BESkIHYb92ENSmgz1QmFwBGIkDIFAAdGAAAQAVoAYiAtiA9gcAKoXM67ADyKAAsjg0FgAK4nHB3AgAWlETxepzJHwhZHov1pHiBjJOzPBX1Sv1utyAA)

(nb : make sure they meet all your constraints, capacitance and voltage ratings are not enough to always define the right capacitor for an application).

For your question about 2 capacitors in series.

In an ideal world, If you put 2 strictly identical capacitors (capacity C1, voltage rating Vmax1, leakage current I_leak_1) in series, then you get an equivalent capacitor with Ceq=C1/2, Vmax_eq=2*Vmax1, I_leak_eq=I_leak_1.

In practice, your capacitors will not be identical (different capacity, different leakage current).

So on the short term, the voltage will not be split identically: the voltage for capacitor 1 will be V1 = C2/(C1+C2) * Vtotal. So one capacitor will see a higher voltage than the other one if capacitance is not perfectly matched (as capacitors are often +-20%, you can get 40% difference if you are unlucky. So you must account for the highest possible voltage.

To make things worse, capacitors leak (and leakage current is not always the same). So one capacitor will weak faster than the other one. Lets suppose C1 leaks, and C2 not (or significantly less). So progressively, C1 will entirely discharge, while C2 is charged up to the total voltage. So voltage C2 sees the full voltage! The easiest solution is to add a resistor in parallel to each capacitor, creating artificially a leakage current greater than the natural one: this ways, you can insure the voltage is split nearly equally (ie with an error in the same range as the tolerance of your resistors).

Comment: You can select some text, click the hyperlink button (ctrl+L) and then paste the link - this makes for much cleaner-looking posts than having a massive link in the text. Also, in English, there's no space before punctuation such as colon (:) and question mark (?).

Comment: I modified the link and the colons (in french there is a space before, therefore firefox automatically inserts the space)

Comment: I think that definitely helps improve the post, thanks.